# Projection from group algebra to an irreducible representation

Tags: representation-theory

It is well known that given a finite group $G$ and an irreducible representation $(V,\rho)$, we have a projector 
$$e_V=\frac{\chi(1)}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^{-1})g\in\mathbb{C}G,$$
such that $e_V^2=e_V$ and gives the projection $\pi:\mathbb{C}G\to V^{\oplus\dim V}$, $x\mapsto xe_V$.

But **how can I find a projector onto a single copy of $V$**, i.e. $\pi:\mathbb{C}G\to V$? (In this case, there should be at least $(\dim V)$ of such projectors.)

If a general solution does not exist, how can I deal with a particular case? Especially I need to find it for $G=A_4$ and $V$ is the unique three dimensional irreducible representation.

Comment: In general, you can't "naturally" separate isomorphic representations, so projecting onto a space consisting of only one isomorphism class of representation is about as good as it gets. If you only want one copy, you can (completely arbitrarily) choose a vector in the subspace, and then take its orbit under $\mathbb{C}G$.